# Compiling for CPAN not possible on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation, gcc

I'm trying to install the Perl module `Linux::Inotify2`. The installation requires some C compiling.

Which compiler CPAN uses is the same one Perl was compiled with. Which one that is can be seen with:

`perl -MConfig -le 'print "@Config{ qw/cc ccflags/ }"'`

Which comes up:

`gcc-4.7 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Now that seems to be a big problem for me because the latest gcc included in raspbian is `4.6`!

As a result, when I try to install `Linux::Inotify2`, I get failures simply because:

`/bin/sh: 1: gcc-4.7: not found`

How can I get around this? Shouldn't Perl have been compiled with gcc-4.6 for raspbian if a newer version wasn't included? Do I have to install gcc-4.7 on my Pi?

**Update:**

Just making a symlink for gcc-4.7 that points to gcc-4.6 seems to be a decent workaround. Though I know this isn't ideal.

Comment: You mean you did symlink from gcc-4.7 to gcc-4.6?

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing the typo. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the Raspbian repository, so you can install it with

`sudo apt-get install liblinux-inotify2-perl`

Bringing in modules from CPAN can affect the stability of a Debian distribution (they have conflicting policies on file modifications), so I don't recommend it unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: you can however install a seperate perl for experamenting using perlbrew

Answer (score 2):

`gcc-4.6` is the default compiler in Debian 6.0; Raspian is a port of Debian 6.0. It is not the only version available, though. You can install different versions, including 4.7 with `apt-get install gcc-4.7`.

Now, you said that `CPAN` modules are compiled with the same version `perl` was compiled with. It is very possible that `perl` on Raspbian was compiled with `gcc-4.7`, then. Raspbian developers tend to use this workaround - using a newer version of `gcc` - when they get some compilers errors building the package.